# WSUS: Content Store drive is full (449 approved update - 1.5 TB space)?

Tags: windows, windows-server, wsus

I have here a WSUS Server on Windows Server Standard 2019.
We have at the moment 449 updates approved, all stored on D:.
D: has 1.5 TB, and it is full!?

Any ideas what I can do? The clean up wizard cleans up nothing, or doesn't work...
Is there a log, where I can find, what updates the server downloaded?

Comment: Why don’t you delete the older updates?

Comment: How should I delete it? The WSUS cleanup wizard don't delete the older updates. All old and superseded updates are declined.

Comment: You need to clarify specifically _how_ the cleanup wizard doesn't work.